# CakePHP Post parameter

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I've some problem in cakephp to send/receive an input form

```
// /View/Services/add_services.ctp
....
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Service', array('action'=>'addServices'))?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input("service_name", array('label'=>false, 'div'=>false, 'class'=>"umstyle5"))?>
<?php echo $this->Form->Submit(__("Add service Type"))?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end();?>

// /Controller/ServicesController
....
public function addServices(){
    ....
    $service_name = $_POST[service_name];
    ....
}
```

The problem is that I receive this error:

Undefined index: service_name [APP/Controller/ServicesController]

What is wrong?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Use $this->request->data.

```
 public function addServices(){
....
  $service_name = $this->request->data['Service']['service_name'];
....
 }
```

Comment: This is correct. When you use the form helper, the default format for an input name is data[Model][field], so the field name here would be data[Service][service_name]. You can access it through $_POST as well but it is strongly recommended to use Cake's built-in $this->request->data as the data is automatically sanitized for you.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you please check the [Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html) properly,

There are clearly mentioned that we can fetch data like...

```
   //Controller/RecipesController.php:
   public function edit($id = null) {
       if (empty($this->request->data)) {
          $this->request->data = $this->Recipe->findById($id);
       } else {
          // Save logic goes here
       }
    }
```